# Removing a specific filename via mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I accomplish the following via mod rewrite in the .htaccess

www.example.com/foo/test.php => www.example.com/foo

Also, this rewrite does not need to be reflected in the browser's address bar, i.e. doesnt need to be a redirect.

Comment: Just want to confirm, when someone types in `www.example.com/foo` you want the server to display `www.example.com/foo/test.php`, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match exactly it would look like this:

```
RewriteRule foo/test.php /foo [L]
```

If you want to match against only the test.php part, it would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/test.php /$1 [L]
```

Either rule will take a request `www.example.com/foo/test.php` and internally rewrite it to `/foo` and serve /foo to the browser.